# how to block Url to all user except super admin

Tags: php, laravel

it should forbid that the user grabs this url:

?main_title=banner

?main_title=law

?main_title=faq

with this

```
if(\Auth::user()->hasRole(['super_admin']))
```

Comment: What's your question? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: if someone who is not a super admin enter the url in the browser, he would like to get the error 404 out of him. sorry for bad English

Comment: Read more about Laravel Middleware. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware

Comment: So did you do this? What exactly is your question? You posted one `if` statement, but what happened when you did this?

Comment: I did not do anything, I need help with everything ;)

Comment: Check this link, might be helpful https://laravel.io/forum/02-17-2015-laravel-5-routes-restricting-based-on-user-type

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are using `spatie/laravel-permission` based on your example code.

`Laravel Permission` comes with built-in role [middlewares](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#using-a-middleware)

One of the ways you could use them is by grouping the routes you want to be accessible only by super admins

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:super_admin']], function () {
    // YOUR ROUTES HERE
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to using the middlewares ,

So in your case first create a Trait for roles

```
public function isSuperadmin(){
       return Auth::user()->role->role=='superadmin';
}
```

After that create a middlewar like `superadmin` for the superuser and in that first include your trait

```
use App\Traits\Roles;
```

after that

```
 use Roles;
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!$this->isSuperadmin())
        {
            return back();
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

and just register the middleware in the app/http/kernal.php in `protected $routeMiddleware` function

```
'superadmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\superadmin::class,
```

so it's make your life very easy now you don't need to check the url or role every time , for any url you want to block for other users just use

```
Route::get('/?main_title=law', 'HomeController@function')->middleware('superadmin')->name('admin-dashboard-home');
```

so if the user role is superadmin then he is allow to assess the url you can redirect the other users or show the error message :)